# Does anyone know what this equation is?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Sorry for being so vague, but I am not sure how to look this one up myself.
[image]

I've had a shirt with this on it for something like 20 years now and everyone I've shown it to says they don't know what it is. I guess I'm not surprised. Does anyone here know what this equation means?

Comment: Also, the shirt must have superb quality if you can wear it for so many years...

Comment: @user14717 - Bubbles probably knows more about math than I do. But I have the common sense to not wear it around. What if it's a higher mathematics joke like the equivalent of 1 + 1 = 9. anyone who can read it might be laughing that you would wear such an incorrect equation and get a good giggle at your foolishness... never know.

Comment: @Mau314 Back in the day, things were made to last!

Comment: No, it's in ruins. I kept it because I never knew what it was. It's virtually unrecognizable now, but I can piece together the symbols

Comment: you could use the tag quantum mechanics^^

Comment: Thanks. Updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Schrödinger's equation. Try to read this before your question gets removed by the moderation :)

Comment: Awesome! thank you so much. Funny thing is I have a sticker on my car that claims to be schrodinger's equation.... hmm

Comment: Don't tell me - your car will start only half the time?

Comment: My car is theoretically in the garage. But it might not be also. Kind of like a joke about the possibility of it being stolen while I'm not watching. I doubt anyone has ever made that connection though.

Comment: @KaiQing You don't know if your car is in the garage. It's there or it's not there. You have here a mixed quantum state. You have to go in your garage to see if the car is there or not. This is then a pure quantum state.

Comment: Cop: do you know at what speed you were driving?!!
@KaiQing: no clue - but I know exactly where I was.

Comment: lol. then my snarkiness gets me thrown in a jail cell where I know where I am but to them I am either in the cell or not. I compared the shirt to the car. Yeah, I can see it now. Where the upside down delta is -  the sticker uses a longer form, but it looks like I should have at least recognized enough to think it might be schrodinger's instead of just being totally clueless. Course, it's not like I carry the shirt around. I forgot I even had it until a few months ago.